# How to authenticated multiple table in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have a two tables in database
1. users(default user table)
2. suspend_users(only two column:- id, email)

now i want to first check in the "suspend_user" table user email exist or not if user email exist in the "suspend table" authentication failed message shows.
now i do not understand that how to check second table(suspend_users) first and how to check multiple table authenticate

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand exactly what you mean, you can check first if the mail exists on the suspend_table and after check login:

example:

```
    if (SuspendedUser::findBy(['email' => $user_email])) {
     // go back to what else... throw expetion etc....
    }

   if (Auth::attempt(email, pass)) {} // check login
```

Comment: did not work this logic.
In the auth controller
`protected function authenticated($request)
    {
       
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        
        if (SuspendUser::find(['email' => $email]))
        {
           dd('suspend user'); 
        }
         else if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1]))
        {
dd('normal user')
       }
}`

Answer (score 0):

you can easily authenticate multiple table in laravel 5.1 and above. 
http://blog.sarav.co/multiple-authentication-in-laravel/